# external script from views.py with Pandas

Tags: django, pandas, django-views

I am trying to execute a script that uses Pandas external from views.py in Django.

I have tried all the solutions that I have found here, but I continue to receive this message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

while Padas is correctly installed and it works fine. If I run the script from the terminal it works, Panda from views.py works, but not from the external file (prova.py).

```
##views.py


from subprocess import run,PIPE
import sys

import subprocess

def external(request):
        
    path = 'D:\Django_Progetti(miei)\TEST_rinfresco\gestionecontatti\contatti\management\commands\prova.py'
    out = subprocess.run(['python', path], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = out.stdout.decode('utf-8')

    return HttpResponse(output)
```

```
##prova.py
import pandas as pd


print("Example")
```